# Rolle's theorem question

Tags: calculus

Let $f(x)=\sin2x/e^{2x}$. Note that $f$ is continuous on $[0,\pi/2]$, and differentiable on $(0,\pi/2)$, with $f(0)=f(\pi/2)=0$. So by Rolle's theorem, there exists a $c\in(0,\pi/2)$ with $f'(c)=0$.

How can we find this $c$ to verify the claim of Rolle's theorem?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Did you choose the tag randomly?Do you know the statemen(at least) of Rolle's theorem?

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to ask.

Comment: Is the question basically to show that there's two points $x,y\in[0,\pi/2], x<y$ such that $f(x)=\sin(2x)/e^{2x}=\sin(2y)/e^{2y}=f(y)$, and also there's a point $z\in (x,y)$ such that $f'(z)=0$?

Comment: To find a $c$ such that $f'(c) = 0$ you compute $f'(x)$ and then solve the equation $f'(x) = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

So we have that $f(0)=f(\pi/2)=0$, so by Rolle's theorem there is a (at least one) point $c$ in our interval $(0,\pi/2)$ such that $f'(c)=0$, and let's find it. Solve:

$f'(x)=2e^{-2x}(\cos(2x)-\sin(2x))=0$.

Now $\cos(y)=\sin(y)$ when $y=\pi/4 +2n\pi$, with $n\in\Bbb Z$. So letting $y=2x$, we have that $x=\pi/8$.

We see that as Rolle's theorem claims, we have $0<\pi/8<\pi/2$, and $f'(\pi/8)=0$